# Passing background parameter through tapgesture from list view to new Page in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation

For some time i'm trying to create navigation service in my app while studying Xamarin. My approach here don't foolow mvvm desing pattern but at first i treid to have functionality working on which i will study further. I figured out how to navigate using ItemSelected property in listview through event fired in code-behind file and pass parameter from object placed in listview as a string. I want to changed it for more custom way by adding tap gesture on image not (imagebutton don't even fired event for new page when i added tap gesture on it in xaml file)
This worked for itemselected:

```
private async void SampleItem_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var details = e.Item as SampleModel;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(details));
    }
```

new page codebehind:

```
    public Page1(SimpleModel sample)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var pageServices = new PageServices();
        BackgroundImage = sample.SampleMainBackgroundImage;

    }
```

This is where i need your help : ( app throwing exception when i assing as constructor of new page a string property and bound it to my string backgroundimagebinding (object reference not set to an instance of an object new page) )

```
private async void SampleIcon_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var details = e.Item as SampleModel;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(newPage1(details));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.Item on code below would be the visual element which I think is the image. Hence, it can't be casted as SampleModel.

```
private async void SampleIcon_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var details = e.Item as SampleModel;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(newPage1(details));

}
```

It worked on ListView maybe because you've set the ItemsSource to a list of PageModels. Btw, It would be really helpful next time if you include all related codes. E.g. xaml part. Also, try out debugger tools so you can view the details of the objects passed on the method.